# Use WSDL Services referenced in a .net framework app inside a .net app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wsdl

I Have an ASP. Net APP (.Net Framework 4.6.2) named Host 1 that references a .Net Framework 4.6.2 class library named Global that uses some Wsdl services. These services are referenced in app.config file in Global project and in web.config in Host 1 project.

I have the same architecture with a .Net 7 app that references the same global project.

The wsdl configurations in the global project are overriden by the configuration of the Host 1 (.Net Framework 4.6.2) project but not in the Host 2 (.Net 7)

You can see the schema below to understand where I want to go.

[image]

How could I perform this ?  How could I Use Wsdl services from a Framework project referenced in a .net 7 app ?

Thanks,